# EXTJS Find the parent of a node

Tags: extjs

I need to be able to find a parent of a select node in a tree, however, whenever i use ParentNode it always comes up as 'undefined'  (and i am not selecting the root).  Anybody know a good way to find the parent of a node?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you should try parentNode, not ParentNode. JS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
let parentNode = Ext.getCmp('YourGridId').getRootNode();
```